# Error while trying to connect to SPARK from Rstudio using sparklyr package

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio

I am using the below command to connect to the spark from rstudio :

> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.0.0")

I have tried changing the java versions/path but still getting the same issue.
Can some one please help on this

Error in force(code) : 
  Failed while connecting to sparklyr to port (8880) for sessionid (5308): Gateway in port (8880) did not respond.

```
Path: C:\Users\....\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-submit2.cmd
Parameters: --class, sparklyr.Backend, "C:\Users\......\R\win-library\3.4\sparklyr\java\sparklyr-2.0-2.11.jar", 8880, 5308
```

---- Output Log ----
'C:\Users....\AppData\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache\SPARK-~1.7\bin\SPARK-~4.CMD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

---- Error Log ----

Answer (score 0):

Probably the initial Spark/ dplyr setup is not done. Check "New Connection" button in 'Spark' tab beside 'Environment' tab in Rstudio:

- Select 'Master' as `local`; 'DB interface' as `dplyr`
- Select proper version of Spark & Hadoop; click 'Connect'
- If Spark is not installed in your machine then a pop up will ask you to do
  so.

After this you should be able to execute your code.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

Do let us know what you get after this.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have tried the steps mentioned ,still I am getting the same issue.Could it be the firewall issue.I am setting it up in my company laptop